# Значение выражения p = p*base

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int m, int n);

main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", i, power(2, i), power(-3, i));
    return 0;
}

int power(int base, int n)
{
    int i, p;

    p = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        p = p * base;
    return p;
}
```

Казалось бы такая простая программка, но возникают вопросы. Объясните, пожалуйста, выражение `p = p*base`. Если `p = 1`, а базой принять принять 2 и -3, то непонятно тогда, каким образом инкрементируется p, если о нем в цикле for нету слов. А i<=n, значит цикл идет до тех пор, пока не дойдет до операции возведения в степень 10.

Comment: Упоминание есть:

`p=p*base;`

Эта строчка кода сначала умножает текущее значение `base` на `p`, а затем сохраняет вычисленное значение в `p`.

Comment: Но в прототипе сказано, что power оперирует параметрами int m и int n, а  в самой уже функции m стал базой. Если приглядеться к printf, то мы видем, что за место base там стоит 2 и -3. 
Они умножаются на p, которое равно одному и нигде не инкреминтируется и ему не ставится никаких условий. И цикл for не должен превышать n,но что это за n и чему она относится? Я что-то совсем запутался.

Comment: @proxyarp, уважаемый @gecube уже дал исчерпывающий ответ :)

Comment: > Но в прототипе сказано, что power оперирует параметрами int m и int n

В прототипе формальные аргументы вообще могли быть не названы :-) Например: `int power (int, int);` - этого было бы вполне достаточно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Описание очень смутное. Попытаюсь разъяснить на пальцах. Функция `power`, судя из названия, должна возводить число `base` в степень `n`. Тут возникает один нюанс, что возводить можно и в дробную степень, и в отрицательную. Но в данной ф-ции эти случаи не рассматриваются и предполагается, что `n` - натуральное число (1, 2, 3 ...).  В случае натуральной степени просто идет умножение числа `base` на себя нужное кол-во раз. Для сохранения промежуточного результата используется временная переменная `p`

Comment: Это все понятно, но что подразумевается под числом base в данном коде и что подразумевается под степенью n, которая стоит в ограничении?

Comment: Возведение в степень в данном случае - умножение числа base n раз само на себя. Что и делается в цикле:

    p = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        p = p * base;

В переменной p накапливается произведение, т.е. после выполнения цикла в ней будет храниться результат возведения в степень.

По поводу

> каким образом инкрементируется p, если о нем в цикле for нету слов.

В данном случае телом цикла является p = p * base; Граница тела цикла - точка с запятой.

Comment: А так не проще?


    int power(int base, int n) {
        int w = base;
        int p = 1;
        for (;n > 0; n >>= 1, w *= w)
            if(n & 1) p *= w;
        return p;
    }

Для эстетов предпоследнюю строку можно переписать иначе:

        return (n ? 0 : p);

Comment: @alexlz, так лучше (а можно и вообще без w), но автор точно не поймет.

Особенно return n? ... без комментария, что это индикация ошибки (отрицательная степень не поддерживается).

--

А вообще-то можно преобразовать в ответ и в метках добавить что-то вроде "целая степень" (не знаю как хорошо сформулировать, а то сам бы сделал).

Comment: Ну я же пометил, что это вариант для эстетов. А вот насчёт избыточности w -- как-то сразу и не заметил. Глаз что ли замыливается?

Comment: А еще лучше переписать ф-цию для работы в общем случае, т.е. через натуральный логарифм и экспоненту.

Comment: @gecube Чем лучше? Сильно спорное утверждение.

Comment: Тем что будет работать с произвольными числами...

Comment: @gecube Не всегда такой универсализм оправдан (напр. микроконтроллеры помельче). Опять же экспонента/логарифм => приближённые вычисления...

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо! Я все запомню.